# Can you configure the Multiverse plugin to teleport players to where they were before rather than the spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

Is there a way to make it so it doesn't teleport you to the spawn every time and instead it teleports you to where you were last?

Answer (score 3):

## You can't.

Multiverse does not store where a user last was in any specific dimension. As such there is not a way to do this with the stock plugin. You'll have to edit the plugin or [specify a exact location](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki/Destinations#exact-destinations).

```
/mv tp <PLAYER> e:<WORLD_NAME>:<X>:<Y>:<Z>[:<YAW>:<PITCH>]
```

For example:

```
/mv tp aytimothy e:world:0:0:0
/mv tp aytimothy e:world:100:100:100:90:90
```

---

This behaviour is usually observed when you [bungiecord](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/) different servers together. Even though it may seem seamless, just like Multiverse, these are actually completely different servers with different worlds/inventories/locations/saves/etc.